# Opentelemetry Collector mapping metric name to labels

Tags: open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I am trying to replace statsd-exporter with the OpenTelemetry Collector. In this case, we have metrics with parts of their names that need to be extracted into labels. With the statsd exporter, we have mappings similar to [this statsd-exporter example](https://github.com/prometheus/statsd_exporter?tab=readme-ov-file#glob-matching):

```
mappings:
- match: "test.dispatcher.*.*.*"
  name: "dispatcher_events_total"
  labels:
    processor: "$1"
    action: "$2"
    outcome: "$3"
    job: "test_dispatcher"
- match: "*.signup.*.*"
  name: "signup_events_total"
  labels:
    provider: "$2"
    outcome: "$3"
    job: "${1}_server"
```

I'm looking at reproducing the same effect with the OpenTelemetry Collector. Have tried the `metricstransformprocessor` and `transformprocessor` but have yet been able to reproduce this functionality.

Comment: What kind of receiver do you have for these metrics on OTEL collector side?

Comment: I would try `attributesprocessor` - there is `extract`, which may be useful

Comment: Using a statsd receiver - trying to 1:1 replace statsd-exporter

Comment: Some receivers supports operators, but that's not case of statsd receiver. You may try `udpreceiver` and then `operators` to transformate body into desirated format. But udpreceiver is for logs, so then it should be converted to metric somehow (maybe you can route it with `router` operator. Or standard metric pipeline approach with `attributesprocessor`. But don't expect single step solution. It can be multiple steps/processors until you have desired format - be creative and test each small step with `debug` exporter.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out an answer using the [transform processor](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/processor/transformprocessor).

The following transforms will extract tokens from the metrics name and add them as tags, rename the metric to a common name, and finally add an extra tag. This functionality directly replaces the first example given for statsd-exporter.

```
processors:
  transform:
    error_mode: ignore
    metric_statements:
    - context: datapoint
      statements:
      - merge_maps(attributes, ExtractPatterns(metric.name, "^test\\.dispatcher\\.(?P<processor>.*)\\.(?P<action>.*)\\.(?P<outcome>.*)"), "insert")
      - replace_pattern(metric.name, "^test\\.dispatcher\\.(?P<processor>.*)\\.(?P<action>.*)\\.(?P<outcome>.*)", "dispatcher_events_total")
      - set(attributes["job"], "test_dispatcher")
```